# Дата создания и обновление записи в таблице mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос, который записывает данные в таблицу. Есть столбцы: `dt_create` и `dt_update` . Выполняем запрос и данные записываются, и в `dt_create` дата создания. Ещё раз выполняем запрос, соответственно в `dt_create` дата записи, а в `dt_update` дата обновления. Как сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дату создания можно вносить в БД с помощью [триггера](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189799%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) `ON INSERT`, а дату обновления при помощи триггера `ON UPDATE`.

Например. Вносим дату создания в триггере `ON INSERT`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table_1] SET dCreate=GETDATE() WHERE id=(SELECT id from inserted);
```

Внесение даты обновления в  триггере `ON UPDATE` выполняется аналогично, только вместо поля `dCreate`, будет, например, `dUpdate`.

В качестве альтернативы можно вместо прямых запросов использовать [хранимые процедуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms345415%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). И в них выполнять операции добавления:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1] (...,dCreate) VALUES (...,GETDATE());
```

И обновления:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table_1] SET dUpdate=GETDATE() WHERE id=...;
```

Для поля с датой создания записи есть ещё 3й вариант. Назначить ему в качестве значения по умолчанию текущую дату/время.

Comment: можете пример показать

Comment: @propro17, пример команды, которая должна выполняться в триггере, и ссылку на документацию добавил в ответ. Думаю, теперь сможете разобраться.

Comment: Э... ну нельзя же обновлять таблицу в том же триггере, который обрабатывает событие над этой таблицей! Это, как минимум, лишние дисковые операции!

Comment: мне надо это сделать в C#. `string str = string.Format(" *тут код* ")`. Можно так?

Answer (score 3):

Можете попытаться использовать триггер [`INSTEAD OF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189799%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), чтобы переопределить эти поля. Но такой триггер несовместим с каскадными операциями.

Поэтому стандартный подход для применения подобных правил - создание хранимой процедуры, которая будет вызываться вместо INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. Так, все ORM умеют вызывать хранимые процедуры для совершения операций над объектами.

Еще один вариант - можно создать вид (view), и повесить INSTEAD OF-триггер на него. Такой подход совместим с каскадными операциями.

---

PS но в современных проектах правильным способом будет использование БД только как хранилища данных, а все подобные правила можно вынести уже в слой доступа к данным.

Comment: Насчёт использования БД только как хранилища."Современный", увы, понятие относительное. Такой подход применялся повсеместно до внедрения поддержки программирования в СУБД. Но, суть не в этом. Даже если это действительно оправдано. Сразу возникает ряд вопросов относительно, как минимум, модификации бизнес логики и безопасности. Не говоря уже о том, что в таком случае часто приходится вручную делать то, что СУБД делает автоматически. Конечно, всё это существенно экономит ресурсы сервера. Только, главное чтобы для экономии 1 рубля в итоге не пришлось тратить 10 (это я образно).

Comment: @Streletz в том-то и дело, что автоматически БД эти поля не проставляет

Comment: Применительно к данному топику, если честно, то не совсем так. При желании можно сделать, чтобы СУБД полностью сама проставила дату/время создания записи. Например, задать для поля соответствующее значение по умолчанию (тогда даже никакая программная логика не нужна!). С обновлением, согласен, несколько сложнее.